# Sqlalchemy convert epoch time to date in group by

Tags: python, python-2.7, orm, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am using Sqlalchemy as ORM for PSQL db. My timestamps are stores as epoch times in my database eg, 1525868337991. (in milli sec)

I am writing a query to get count of employees on a particular date(grouping by on date). I am not able to find any way by which, I can convert **epoch to date** in my ORM query, like psql has **to_timestamp**. The query is written below :

```
employees_details = db.session.query(
      func.count(EmployeeInfo.id).label("employee_count"), EmployeeInfo.employee_created_on, EmployeeSourceInfo.employee_source_display_name
    ).join(
      EmployeeSourceInfo, EmployeeInfo.lead_source_id == EmployeeSourceInfo.id
    ).group_by(func.as_utc(EmployeeInfo.employee_created_on), EmployeeSourceInfo.employee_source_display_name).all()
```

Comment: Why don't you then just use the single argument form of `to_timestamp()`?

Comment: @IljaEverilä I don't SqlAlchemy has to_timestamp() as its there psql. If its there, please let me know how to use it..

Comment: `func` in SQLAlchemy is generic. You can use it to generate pretty much any function expression necessary. `func.xyzzy(1, 2)` is just fine, if your database has such a function.

Comment: @IljaEverilä Thanks, I am able to get but still I am not able to extract date from it.. Below is the query 

`func.timezone('UTC',func.to_timestamp(EmployeeInfo.employee_created_on/1000))`

I am dividing by 1000, as my timestamps are in milliseconds

Comment: Using the above query I am not able to perform group_by as date is returned as an instance of datetime like
`datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 9, 7, 34, 2, 744000)`

Answer (score 4):

The [`func`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/functions.html) in SQLAlchemy is generic and can be used to produce almost any SQL function expression. With this in mind you can simply replace `func.as_utc` with

```
func.to_timestamp(EmployeeInfo.employee_created_on / 1000.0)
```

To then truncate it to a date either cast it as one:

```
from sqlalchemy import Date

func.to_timestamp(EmployeeInfo.employee_created_on / 1000.0).cast(Date)
```

or use the Postgresql specific function `date_trunc()` to reduce the resulting timestamp to day precision:

```
func.date_trunc('day', func.to_timestamp(EmployeeInfo.employee_created_on / 1000.0))
```

Comment: The former approach to cast dates is a good approach, but it returns date as an instance of datetime class. **datetime.date(2018, 4, 9)** . Is there any way to convert them to exact date in query itself ?
Without that I have to run a loop and convert each date into **isoformat**

Comment: What do you mean by "exact date"?

Comment: By **exact date** I mean in the format **2018-04-09** (YYYY-mm-dd) isoformat, whereas the cast query above returns date as an instance of datetime class **datetime.date(2018, 4, 9)**