# How to cast integer (epoch) column to datetime in sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, datetime, sqlalchemy, epoch

I'm using sqlalchemy to query a database and have a Table.c.Field object from inspect, where Field is of type integer (e.g., 1596657600). How do I cast that field to a datetime? In the query I want to cast Field as datetime, then later extract and groupby dayofweek (or some other aspect of datetime). But first I need to cast Field as a date or datetime.

I have tried a few ways, but all fail. In the code below I first import sqlalchemy as sa.

I tried

```
sa.func.to_timestamp(Table.c.Field / 1.0).cast(sa.Date)
```

as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53371655/sqlalchemy-convert-epoch-time-to-date-in-group-by). But it produces the error: `no such function: to_timestamp`.

I tried

```
Table.c.Field.cast(sa.DateTime)
```

as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17333014/convert-selected-datetime-to-date-in-sqlalchemy). But as in that link it produces the error: `Couldn't parse datetime string '1596657600' - value is not a string`.   If it helps, the database I am querying is also Sqlite, but I would like my solution to work for any integer field from any database.

I also tried

```
sa.cast(Table.c.Field, SQA.Interval)
```

but it produced the same error: `Couldn't parse datetime string '1596657600' - value is not a string`.

If the solution is to create some special function (e.g., Fx) to do the conversion, to be used as

```
(Table.c.Field).Fx()
```

what would that function look like? Or what kind of function would do the trick? I cannot write to the database, and need to do all calculations (casting, grouping, filtering, etc.) via a single sqlalchemy query.

Comment: you could turn it into a python datetime first https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694487/in-python-how-do-you-convert-seconds-since-epoch-to-a-datetime-object

Comment: I need to do all calculations (casting, grouping, filtering, etc.) via sqlalchemy, as the final query will be complicated. Also, I cannot write to the database.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution in the [docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/custom_types.html), but I wasn't sure at first how to apply it in my case.

First, create a new type that accepts integers, then simply cast Field to that type. I first import sqlalchemy as SQA and import tzinfo and datetime and timedelta from datetime.

```
class MyEpochType(SQA.types.TypeDecorator):
    impl = SQA.types.Integer
    epoch = datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, tzinfo=pytz.timezone('UTC'))
    
    def process_bind_param(self, value, dialect):
        pass # not needed in my use case

    def process_result_value(self, value, dialect):
        # either of the two returns below, or similar ones
        #return self.epoch + timedelta(seconds=value )
        return datetime.fromtimestamp(value).isoformat()

Table.c.Field.cast(MyEpochType)
```

The above solution will not allow for a group_by on the transformed values (e.g., a datetime or string). For this, a better solution is to use the native functions of the underlying database. In my case it is Sqlite, and would be called similar to that below:

```
SQA.func.strftime('%H%M',  
  SQA.func.datetime(Table.c.Field, 'unixepoch')).label('someLabel')
```

Here as an example I am calling two different Sqlite functions and giving the result a label. Each database has its own set of particular functions that can be called.